# vSphere client can not be started

Tags: windows, vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere

I have been using ESXi4 with windows (Windows7) management software of vSphere client for long. When trying booting vSphere client for some reason, the system said something like "vpxClient stopped running. Trying to find a measure to treat against this incident" . And it never boot.

When installing vSphere client at the first time of ESXi installation, I have add a sentence like

in the VpxClient.exe.config file.

Also I have copied and pasted system.dll file into Program Files(x86）\vmware\Infrastructure\Virtual Infrastructure Client\Launcher\lib

How can I reboot vSphere Client ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the v4.0 update 1 version of the VSClient? it's the only one that's supported with W7.